# Visual studio stopped working error message

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have recently installed a windows update which only says Security update.
Now when I open my Visual Studio 2010 project I receive an error message saying "Microsoft Visual Studio has stopped working" and here are the other details:

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: devenv.exe
  Application Version:  10.0.30319.1
  Application Timestamp:    4ba1fab3
  Fault Module Name:    fpeditax.dll
  Fault Module Version: 10.0.30319.1
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ba20479
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0018b03a
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.28
  Locale ID:    1033

Additional information about the problem:
  LCID: 1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Please can anyone assist me with this issue?

Thank you in advance

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2201993

Comment: can't download anywhere, plus they say it only works for a day

Answer (score 0):

Really sounds like a .EXE (devenv.exe) or an associated DLL (fpeditax.dll) has become corrupted. You can waste days on trying to figure out which one and why. I recommend you just do a fresh install of VS2010 - will take you a lot less time.

Comment: Okay - strip it down to basic's - this is long and time consuming. Do a restore to the point before you did the Windows Update (you have Restore Points enabled right?). Test that VS works. Make a NEW named Restore Point. Slowly install updates, testing VS at each point. When it breaks, you know which update is the issue - so DONT install that update. Or..... do a clean install of Windows, patch everything. THEN install VS.

Comment: I Can't Restore, I will loose to much data.